# Retrieving Data from Firebase to label 'Swift Project'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, data-retrieval

What's the correct syntax for the function that I should use to retrieve data from firebase to a label?

For Example, I want to retrieve the email and the password as [in the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chl73.png)

I have tried this code bellow but it did not work! It retrieved no thing in the simulator!!

```
    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot  in let m = snapshot.value.objectForKey("users/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/email") as? String
        self.EmailLabel.text = m

    })
```

Comment: How do you initialize your `ref` object? What is the result of pritning the snapshot object?

Comment: Here’s how I initialize the ref variable: 
var ref = Firebase(url:"https://myproject.firebaseio.com")
When I tried to print the email after retrieving, it print nil in the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
var ref = Firebase(url:"YOUR_URL_PATH/Users")

ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let m = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Email")as?
        self.EmailLabel.text = m
}, withCancelBlock: { error in
    println(error.description)
})
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: It gives me an error in the line:
    let m = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Email")
I did add:    
    as? String 
at the end of the line. 
    let m = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Email") as? String

but when I simulate it gives me nothing in the simulator!!

Comment: Try to debug code and check did you got data in snapshot?

Comment: Still does not work. See What I get in the picture: http://b.top4top.net/p_68ejnc1.png

Comment: @Mariah There is a problem in creating object of ref Please set full path of the location. This path will end at "Users"

Comment: But how can I set full bath and where? Here's my firebase dashboard: http://c.top4top.net/p_6825ro1.png